# Graph Theory Algorithm - Playoffs

Tags: graph-theory

Given $n$ players, every time $2$ players match against each other, one goes home and one stays. Until there's only one left.

Given the knowledge that player $x$ can beat player $y$, which algorithm can be used to make sure that a specific player will be the ultimate winner?

I need a graph theory solution, any suggestions?

It may not be possible to arrange a specific winner.

Comment: The question isn’t entirely clear. Do you know the results of **all** possible pairings? And are there any limitations on how you arrange the tree? Are you allowed, for instance, to make it horribly unbalanced, so that the desired winner plays only one match?

Comment: all possible pairing results are known, and the tree can be unbalanced.

Comment: If every player can beat player $a$, then there is no way for player $a$ (the specially chosen specific player) to be the ultimate winner. Do you mean for player $x$ to be the ultimate winner?

Answer (score 1):

This isn’t something with which I’m very familiar, so you may get a better answer, but in the meantime perhaps these comments will help. Let $G$ be the directed graph showing the outcomes of each pairing, and let $v$ be the desired winner. It’s not too hard to see that $v$ can be the overall winner if and only if there is an [arborescence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arborescence_%28graph_theory%29), or rooted directed spanning tree, for $G$ with $v$ as its root. That doesn’t finish the job, because once you have that, you can generally set up the tournament tree in a variety of ways. For example, if $A$ can beat $B$ and $C$, and $C$ can beat $D,E$, and $F$, you could have either of these tournament trees:

```
                             A                                 A
                            / \                               / \  
                           A  B/C                            A  B/C  
                              / \                               / \  
                             B   C                             B   C  
                                / \                               / \  
                               C   D                             /   \
                              / \                               C    E/F  
                             C  E/F                            / \   / \  
                                / \                           C   D E   F
                               E   F
```

However, it shouldn’t be too hard to work out an algorithm for converting an arborescence with $v$ as root to a tournament tree with $v$ as winner, and [this algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%27_algorithm), with all weights taken to be $1$, appears to solve the problem of finding an arborescence.